# inthe terminal it says: "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'"

Tags: python

I don't know yet if the logic works cause it will make an error on line 3:
What I want to do is to make a do while function that only takes an int.
it says in line "  if n.isdigit(): " that "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'". I thought that if I use input to from a user it will return a string value?

```
def main():
    num = get_int()
    even = []
    odd = []
    arr = []
    #con_num = int(num)
    while num != 0:
        arr.append(num % 10)
        arr = arr / 10
    # divides the number
    for i in arr:
        if (i % 2 == 0):
            even.append(num % 10)
            num / 10
        else:
            odd.append(num % 10)
            num / 10

    # even * by 2
    for i in even:
        even[i] *= 2
        if  even[i] > 9:
            even.append(even[i] % 10)
            even[i] = even[i] / 10

#THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM COMES
def get_int():
    try:
        while True:
            n = input("Number: ")
            if n.isdigit():
                break
    except ValueError:
        print("You need to input integers only!")
    return n

main()
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using? In Python 3, `input()` returns a string. In Python 2, it parses the input as an expression and returns the result.

Comment: You should be using Python 3, as Python 2 has been EOLed.

Comment: nvm I answered it thanks

Comment: I didnt saved it. btw Im using vscode